# What canvas am I drawing to in myLocationOverylay

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the `MyLocationOverlay` in Google Maps API and I don't understand what canvas I should pass to `drawMyLocation`. Here is some of my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;

public class MyLocationDot extends MyLocationOverlay {
    private MapView mMapView;

    public MyLocationDot(Context context, MapView mapView) {
        super(context, mapView);
        mMapView = mapView;
    }

    protected void drawMyLocation(Canvas canvas) {
        super.drawMyLocation(canvas, mMapView, getLastFix(), getMyLocation(), 0);
    }


}
```

And in my onCreate() of the map activity:

```
// my location
        myLocation = new MyLocationDot(this, mapView);
        myLocation.enableMyLocation();
        myLocation.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myLocation.drawMyLocation(WhatCanvas??);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong you don't explicitly pass a Canvas: you pass your overlay to the MapActivity and it deals with that for you.

EDIT: so something like this.

```
 mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
 me = new MyLocationDot(this, mapView);
 mapView.getOverlays().add(me);
```

Comment: I think you may be right, all I want to do is display the current location with MyLocationOverlay, if I don't have to extend it that would be great